# remove a "bad address" error from the standard output on the linux terminal

Tags: linux, output, fuse

when attempting to copy a file inside a mounted directory, I got this message printed on my terminal:

```
cp: writing `file': Bad address
```

However, the copying operation is successfully executed, but I just want to delete this message (for a presentation purpose). any idea how to remove this warning (or error) ?

Comment: Er… fix your FUSE filesystem such that it does't happen?

Comment: how is that possible ?

Comment: Depends entirely on what you are doing.

Comment: okay
how can I redirect the standard error on linux terminal (by doing 2>&1) but for every command I execute, so I don't need to write that at the end of every command ?!

Comment: **Fix the underlying issue.** Don't just try to ignore it.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, and as I said, the copying operation is working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could redirect errors to /dev/null or to a log file, like this :

```
cp a b 2>/dev/null
```

or

```
cp a b 2>errors.log
```

Comment: I meant programatically (Java) ?

Comment: Why are you using a command line to copy a file in Java ? You can do it using Streams or even better, using a library like [commons-io](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html)